# Create one instance of WCF Proxy for all ASP.NET MVC lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api, RESTful, with Visual Studio 2012, C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I will use this Web Api to consume another WCF SOAP service and I want to create the client proxy for that WCF service when my WebApi starts.

How can I do that?

I know that Ninject works this way, it is always available. But I can't find an example about how I can do it.

Or maybe I have to declare the WCF proxy as an instance field inside each controller class.

Comment: have you thought of/tried the singleton pattern?

Comment: @rik.vanmechelen Yes, but the problem is where to put that instance, on Global.asax?

Comment: you can just create it anywhere you want. a static constructor (as shown in my answer) will make sure it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, reusing the same WCF Client Proxy generally yields the best performance and can be particularly beneficial if you use security features, which have a high initial security negotiation cost. Note: when reusing proxy instances, your code surely need to check the state of the client proxy before communication.

To that end, you have a few options, either directly reusing the same client proxy object or  using a proxy ChannelFactory with caching.  The following MSDN blog post, although a bit older, provides a good explanation of the options and guidance regarding best practices.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738757.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question: how can I expose that proxy for the rest of the application (the ApiControllers)? Do I have to create a static property on Global.asax? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then the following link should help.  http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/creating-a-wcf-service-proxy-with-channelfactory/

Comment: Though reusing a cached proxy offers the best performance, it may pose a **security risk** due to cached credentials; rights or claims; if an admin has changed the user's access rights in the intervening time.  Such rights may not be checked again until the user logs in again.  Of course the server could flag this but then that means that all requests be routed to a check-for-expired-claims processor in any event which might degrade the performance boost achieved prior.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of singleton thing as follows:

```
public class WFCSingleton
{
    public static WFCSingleton SingletonInstance

    static WFCSingleton()
    {
        SingletonInstance = new SingletonInstance();
    } 

    private SingletonInstance(){}
}
```

Now you should always use it though WFCSingleton.SingletonInstance
The static constructor will only be called once before an instance is created (that is just how it works [check msdn for more on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

All additional logic can be put in WFCSingleton as instance methods/properties.